# Changing bracketed header files does not trigger recompilation in MCVS 15

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, header-files

When modifying header files which are included using angle brackets MCVS 15 does not trigger recompilation of the source files. However, if the brackets are changed to quotes the recompilation is triggered. Is this expected? Is there an option to make modifications of header files which are included with angle brackets to trigger recompilation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, in order to help us to help you, can you give some 'example' code with the header declarations. (Normally, angle-brackets are used for *system* headers, which you shouldn't really be changing.)

Comment: Also, maybe take a look here: [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include “filename”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)